# CentOS: installing a GD Library

Tags: linux, centos, php

I'm running PHP version 5.3.5.

Now I need to install GD Library.

When I run: --> **yum info php-gd**, it says Missing php-common 5.1.6-43.el5_10.

> php-gd-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
>     --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-43.el5_10 is needed by package php-gd-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64 (updates)
>   Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-43.el5_10 is needed by package php-gd-5.1.6-43.el5_10.x86_64 (updates)

php-common-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1 is already installed in my server. I cannot verify why php-gd is depending on php-common-5.1.6.

How can I install GD library 5.3.5 in server without having to do upgrading to php version?

Thanks & Regards,
Nge

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, when you use the CentOS repositories, is `php53-gd`, not `php-gd`.

That said, it sounds like you have installed PHP 5.3 from another repo, so you'll likely want to make sure you're trying to install [that repo's equivalent of `php53-gd`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20652064/dir//com/php-gd-5.3.23-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm.html).

EDIT: Or make sure you're enabling that repo when you try to install the package.

Comment: When I run **yum install php53-gd**, it says "php53-common conflicts with php-common".

Can you advise how can I make GD not pointing to repository php-gd?

Comment: Seeing `php-common-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1` tells me you're using [Remi Colette's repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/English-FAQ). You could try `yum --enablerepo=remi install php-gd` in case it's disabled, as it is by default. I'm not sure if you can still install packages from PHP 5.3 though, as I see 5.4 when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are two answers to solve this issue.

One is the answer given by @miken32.
I tried the comment `yum --enablerepo=remi install php-gd`. It is resolved. But it is upgraded to 5.4 as mentioned. For people who love to upgrade the latest version, I recommend you to use this.

As for me, there are many applications in the same server and it can happen Version incompatible issue. So I decide to find out the way without so much changes in Version. Thanks Miken for taking time to help me.

Second is I reference to the link below and it works for me. Php version might slightly change from 5.3.5 to 5.3.28.
http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.6-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common

I hope this will help people who are experiencing the same situation.

Thanks & Best regards,
Nge

Answer (score 0):

Because someone might use PHP version 5.4, for this version I had to use:

```
sudo yum install gd gd-devel php54-gd
```